# GWT. Set value to JavaScript variable from GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

How I can set value from GWT application to JavaScript variable defined in HTML file? This code seems doesn't work:

```
private static native void setMyValue(String myValue) /*-{
    $wnd.variableName =  myValue;
}-*/;
```

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? It should.

Comment: It should work make sure javascript variable in $wnd context. and refer this link for further detail http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

Comment: These links may help you - http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/ajax/GWT-JSNI.pdf - http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#sharing